# Solving second order linear ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having trouble solving this differential equation:

$$y'' + 2(x-x^{3})^{-1}y'=0\\$$

do I find the integrating factor:

$$u= e^{\int 2(x-x^3)^{-1}}\\$$

or is there another method?

This differential equation is part of a larger problem on the reduction of order method, so if this equation I presented here does not make sense or is insolvable by traditional ways, I will include the whole problem.

The included solution, it is $$y_1(x)=x\\$$

Comment: I think integrating factor is the way to go. Well, $\frac{1}{x-x^3} = \frac{1}{x(1-x^2)}$, partial fraction decomposition maybe?

Comment: @BryanChen: You could try letting $y' = v$.

Comment: By the way you did mention reduction of order method, are you given a known solution to the differential equation?

Comment: write $\dfrac{dv}{v}=-2(x-x^3)^{-1}dx$ after BryanChen Changing

Comment: Sorry, I should've given the included solution, it is $$y_1(x)=x\\$$ @Chee Han

Answer (score 1):

I am attaching the solution as an image file. Please find the attachment.

[image]

The integration you can find [Here.](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/integral-calculator/%5Cint%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D%7D%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D-1%7D%20dx)

Comment: Why the downvote. If you don't want just tell we will not give the answers.

Comment: was not me who downvoted

Comment: Okay, this comment was for that who did it.